# Constructing URL based on $routeProvider configuration

Tags: angularjs

In angular.js, is there a built in way to construct URL based on already specified $routeProvider?

Something like Rails' url_for:

```
url_for(:action => 'login', :controller => 'account')
```

or ASP.NET MVC's Url.Action / Url.RouteUrl:

```
Url.RouteUrl(new { controller = "account", action = "login" })
```

Or should I just construct the URL manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with "bare angular" because Angular only recognizes the URL you're trying to access.

However, [Angular-UI's Router](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/#/) allows you to jump to a certain state, thus changing the url based on the state's name.

Answer (score 0):

within an angular app, when you click on a link with href path of `http://localhost/account/login/`. Then Angular steps in, and instead of letting your browser request a page from the server, it intercepts your click event and goes to your routeProvider to see which client-side view to display. Thats why your links work as long as you try not to open them directly.

you can config the routeProvider for this href path `http://localhost/account/login/`, in angular as shown below.

```
   app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('account/login', {templateUrl: 'account/login', controller: 'AccountController'}).
        when('/users', {templateUrl: 'account/users', controller: 'UsersController'}).
        otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
    }]);
```

Here in this

```
when('account/login', {templateUrl: 'account/login', controller: 'AccountController'}).
```

templateUrl, `templateUrl: 'account/login'`, In ASP.NET MVC, it redirects to account -> Controller and login -> Action.

or you can set to static tempalte like this `templateUrl: 'views/user_login.htm'`

controller, `controller: 'AccountController'` is nothing but the AngularJS Controller.